# How to convert bitmap to File without compressing

Tags: android, android-async-http

I need to download image from a server and save it in its original quality, but apparently the after saving the image is compressed and the quality decreased.

I use android-async-http library for http requests. my code of the request and saving file:

```
     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
     client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int arg0, Header[] arg1, byte[] response) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inPreferQualityOverSpeed=true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(response , 0, response .length,bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    bitmapToFile(bitmap);

    });



File bitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap){
    // convert Bitmap to File
    File newImage;
    try {
        newImage = functions.createImageFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newImage);

        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(newImage);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


    return newImage;

}


protected File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that it's the server that compresses the picture?

Comment: "but apparently the image is retrieved compressed and the quality decreased" -- how have you determined this?

Comment: @TimBillström I checked the image on browser (from android device), its size hasn't changed. But  when I downloaded it through the code above its size reduced to the half.

Comment: @CommonsWare I checked the size, in server it 300 kilobyte and after saving it on device it become 150. Could it be decoding problem? how can I check byte[] content before decoding it to ensure that?

Comment: "and after saving it on device it become 150" -- since you have no code in your question that demonstrates this, I have no idea how you saved it. Or do you mean that you are looking at the length of `response`?

Comment: Well, you are compressing it yourself as part of writing out the image, via the `compress()` call.

Comment: @CommonsWare doesn't the quality parameter 100 means not? and how to convert bitmap to File without compressing it?

Comment: "doesn't the quality parameter 100 means not?" -- no. Quoting the documentation for `compress()`: "Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality." "Max quality" does not mean "no compression". "how to convert bitmap to File without compressing it?" -- :: shrug :: you are welcome to write out the `byte[]` directly. But most images are PNG or JPEG, and they are compressed.

Comment: While PNG is a compressed format, it uses **lossless compression** - unlike with a lossy compression such as jpeg, proper handling of the conversion to/from PNG means that you can get the exact original bitmap back.  (OTOH, if colorspace conversions are done, there will be some approximation introduced)

Comment: how can you write out an actual BMP file including header (no compression)?

Answer (score 0):

Do away with that BitmapFactory and just save all the bytes in parameter `byte[] response` directly to file.