# Failed binder transaction

Tags: android, bitmap

My app displays a picture and text, when my user clicks on said picture I wish to enlarge it.

So far I do it through an `Activity` that displays a `Bitmap`:

```
// ImageView containing the image.
final ImageView apd = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.apd_image);

    apd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Save ImageView as Bitmap
            apd.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            apd.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = apd.getDrawingCache();

            // Create intent and set image to display.
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryDetailsActivity.class);               
            intent.putExtra("image", bitmap);

            //Start details activity
            startActivity(intent);
            apd.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
    });
```

Here is the `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery_details_activity);

    Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

But when I click on my picture I receive the following error message in the debugger:

> E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Some research got me to reduce the image quality in order to display it like such:

```
final float densityMultiplier = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

int h = (int) (50 * densityMultiplier);
int w = (int) (h * bitmap.getWidth() / ((double) bitmap.getHeight()));

bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, true);
```

It works, but it's not what I want.

Would there be a way to widen my image and keep its quality?

**EDIT**:

As recommended I now Save my picture in my file system like such:

```
  private void savePicture(String filename, Bitmap b, Context ctx){
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        FileOutputStream out;// = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, oos);

        oos.close();
        oos.notifyAll();
        out.notifyAll();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And load it in the activity like such:

```
   private Bitmap loadPicture(String filename) {
    Bitmap b = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ois);
        try {
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

I now want to display it in a bigger size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the image via intent.  Intents are meant to hold a small amount of data, not images.  Write it to the file system, and pass the file name via intent.

Comment: Any example of how this can be achieved?

Comment: @ChristopherK. Writing an image to file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28561263/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-file-without-compressing.

Comment: Where is this image coming from? isnt it already in your file system? Dosnt look like your using the camera

Comment: I get the image's URL via an API and load it through Glide.